# Redux: Passing down Arguments to Actions that could be retrieved from State?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, flux

I have a collection of articles. A user sometimes edits or deletes an article. My app keeps track in the state which article is currently being worked on (call this the `currentArticleId`).

Now when a user edits or deletes an article, would I then give my action-creator the `currentArticleId` as an argument (e.g.: `deleteArticle(this.props.currentArticleId)`), or would I *NOT* do that and just fire the action creator *without arguments* (e.g.: `deleteArticle()`), and retrieve the `currentArticleId` from state in my action creator?

What's best practice here? Why would I choose one solution over the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by state you mean Redux application state, then there is no right or wrong answer. You can even have two actions - `deleteCurrentArticle()` or `deleteArticle(articleId)` and use whatever suits you more.

However if you're asking about the component state, I think action creators should be decoupled from components. So I'd prefer passing the currentArticleId as an argument.

Comment: I did indeed mean Redux-State. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would make your action creator more flexible by passing in an article ID, then your delete article action could delete the current article, or any other article it wanted to.

edit: I would like to add that there are usually better alternatives to keeping information like this in the global state. If you're only editing/deleting a single article on a page, then you could have a URL like `article/{id}/edit` and then grab the ID from there and pass it into what you need, or if you have a list of articles that each have editors, consider passing the article ID as a prop into the editor component.